# Counting the rows based on two other column values, and manipulate the value in a loop through one of these column values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

There are three columns: website, Date ("%Y %m"), click_tracking (T/F). I would like to add a variable describing the number of websites whose click tracking = T in each month / the number of all website in that month.

I thought the steps would be something like:

```
aggregate(sum(df$click_tracking = TRUE), by=list(Category=df$Date), FUN = sum)
as.data.frame(table(Date))
```

Then somehow loop through Date and divide the two variables above which would have been already grouped by Date. How can I achieve this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create the proportion of websites with click tracking (out of all websites) per month.

```
aggregate(data=df, click_tracking ~ Date, mean)
```

Comment: does "mean" give proportion? also, this returns that "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

Comment: Mean will give proportion of a logical.  For example `mean(c(TRUE,FALSE))` is 0.5.  Because TRUE is coerced into 1 and FALSE into 0.   I had assumed your click tracking variable was a logical based on your example.

Answer (score 2):

If we are creating a column, then do a group by 'Date' and get the `sum` of 'click_tracking' (assuming it is a logical column - TRUE/FALSE) iin `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Date) %>%
   mutate(countTRUE = sum(click_tracking))
```

If the column is `factor`, convert to `logical` with `as.logical`

```
df %>%
   group_by(Date) %>%
   mutate(countTRUE = sum(as.logical(click_tracking)))
```

If it is to create a summarised output

```
df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(countTRUE = sum(click_tracking))
```

---

In the OP's code, `=` (assignment) is used instead of `==` in `sum(df$click_tracking = TRUE)` and there is no need to do a comparison on a logical column

```
aggregate(cbind(click_tracking = as.logical(click_tracking)) ~ Date, FUN = sum)
```

Comment: this returns an error message - "Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors" I was trying to get a count of those whose click_tracking = TRUE, and it seems sum() cannot achieve this?

Comment: what is the result of `class(df$click_tracking)`

Comment: @Michelle I assumed that the column is `logical` instead of `factor`.  If it is factor, then you may need to convert to `logical` with `as.logical` i.e. `as.logical(factor(c("TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE")))#
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE`

Comment: @GeorgeSavva It's a factor with two levels - true, false - but somehow cannot be converted to logical through as.logical

Comment: @Michelle For me, it is working though `as.logical(factor(c("true", "false", "true")))#
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE` in `R`, the logical values are upper case `TRUE/FALSE` without quotes, but `as.logical` will coerce the `"true", "false"` etc to logical